# Ruby on rails database queue

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, database

In my ruby on rails web app I want to queue DML operations.

Now I do not know if it would be best use an existing queue (like RabbitMQ) or to write my own but I guess writing my own would be a good idea.

Do you have any tips on how to write a database queue and integrate it in ruby on rails?

Thanks.

Comment: It's somewhat subjective, but I wouldn't write my own, especially as you may not becthat familiar with queues. I would suggest redis and the resque gem,

Comment: Yes I already considered this but did not find a single tutorial on that in connection with databases.

Comment: As Tim said, question is very subjective, however, https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq may help

Comment: We'll in terms of messages redis is the database for the queue, it's very good for somethings - but it's obviously not sql . So, very simplified is you pop something into a queue, and another process consumes it and processes it in someway. Are you concerned about querying whats in the queue, waiting to be consumed? or how to get it into a database as part of the process when it's consumed. Of course you could be set in your decision, so I'll have a little look to see if there is anything to help you, and please ignore the comment :)

Comment: No i cannot use redis. I have an existing MySQL database . i guess to implement it on my own would be a good idea but i do not even know where to Start. My app is very little und the database is not huge

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's quite often you need some consumer-producer implementation on your own. You can create own processor and tasks, it's not so hard. Here is an example you can use. Just implement own backend logic using MySQL.

```rb
module MyJobs
    def self.backend
      @backend
    end

    def self.backend=(backend)
      @backend = backend
    end

  class Processor
    def self.start(concurrency = 1)
      concurrency.times { |n| new("Processor #{n}") }
    end

    def initialize(name)
      thread = Thread.new do
        loop do
          payload = MyJobs.backend.pop
          worker_class = payload[:worker]
          worker_class.new.perform(*payload[:args])
        end
      end

      thread.name = name
    end
  end

  module Worker
    module ClassMethods
      def perform_async(*args)
        MyJobs.backend.push(worker: self, args: args)
      end
    end
  end
end

MyJobs.backend = Queue.new
MyJobs::Processor.start(5)
```